# Weyl's asympotic law for eigenvalue : $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{M(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\sum_p \frac{A(D_p)}{4 \pi}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, spectral-theory, proof-explanation

In the book Strauss W.A. Partial differential equations - An introduction (Wiley, $2008$, $1$nd Ed.) page $310 - 311$, it is probably a silly question, but is there anyone could give me a hint how to obtain $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{M(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\sum_p \frac{A(D_p)}{4 \pi}$? I am stocked on the problem for a while and I don't know how to solve it.

**Edit :** I am able to know why $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{M(\lambda)}{\lambda}= \frac{A(\text{rectangle})}{4 \pi}$ (example on the rectangle page $307$), but when we let $\lambda$ in an arbitrary planar domain, I dont know why $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{M(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\sum_p \frac{A(D_p)}{4 \pi}$ become true.

> **Proof :** Let $D$ be the union of a finite number of rectangle $D = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup \cdots $ in the plane. Each particular $\mu_n$
>   corresponds to one of these rectangles, say $D_p$ (where $p$ depends
>   on $n$). Let $A(D_p)$ denote the area of $D_p$. Let $M(\lambda)$ be
>   the enumeration function for the sequence $\mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots$
>   define above $$M(\lambda) \equiv \text{the number of } \mu_1, \mu_2,
>  \cdots \text{that do not exceed } \lambda.$$
>
> Then, adding up the integer lattice points which are located within
>   $D$, we get $$\text{(1)} \lim_{\lambda \to \infty}
>  \frac{M(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\sum_p \frac{A(D_p)}{4 \pi}$$ as for the
>   case of a single rectangle. Since $M(\mu_n)=n$, the reciprocal of
>   $(1)$ take the form $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\mu_n}{n}=\sum_p
>  \frac{4 \pi}{A(D)}.$$ By the theorem $5$ it follows that $$\lim_{n \to
>  \infty} \frac{\lambda_n}{n}=\sum_p \frac{4 \pi}{A(D)}.$$

**Clarification :** For the whole domain $D$, we regard the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$. When we regard the domain as $D = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup \cdots$, we know that each $D_i$ has its own set of eigenvalues. Therefore, we combine all the Dirichlet eigenvalues of all of the subdomains $D_1, D_2, \cdots$ into a single increasing sequence $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \cdots$.

Comment: come on ... I'm not insulting you...  and why don't you try understanding the exercice so that you can write it here directly without copying the book ?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? It looks like it is explained in the text. Could you clarify?

Comment: Hmmm... You are "J. Doe", the user who got kicked out of MSE a few days ago. Be careful this time, stop violating MSE rules. In particular, stop linking to pirated material.

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity: Don't introduce links to illegal copies of copyrighted books in your posts, anymore; if the copyright owners find out, they could sue MSE and nobody wants this, right?

Comment: @AlexM. lol who the hell did reproach that there are links to pirated books ? every student in mathematics does that... that's just necessary for studying

Comment: @user1952009: Looking at your comments above, it seems that you have engaged in a conversation half of which got now deleted. Why don't you also delete them, because left alone they don't make any sense now, anymore?

Comment: @AlexM. : who cares ? anyway his question doesn't make any sense to me (I guess there are other implicit facts in his book, about those lattice points, that he didn't copy)

Comment: come on, you don't understand the question yourself, since you copied the book without changing any character

Comment: understanding the question yourself...

Comment: since my 1st comment, I'm saying that your question doesn't mean anything to me, that if we suppose $M(\lambda)/\lambda$ means something, then the rest becomes illogical, same for $\sum_p A(D_p)$ (and there are those "lattice points....")

Comment: @user1952009 I've edited the question, I don't know if it could help you.

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity: Could you make the question self contained? What is $\mu_n$?

Comment: Just define everything: $\mu_n$ is not defined.

Comment: @AlexR. Is it better or you think there exists other things could be improved?

Comment: Check out section 2.2.3 of this: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253/Lecture3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $N_{D_p}(\lambda)$ the number of eigenvalues for the Dirichlet Laplacian on the rectangle $D_p$ that are less than $\lambda$.

Then, and this is what you seem to be missing, since the sequence $\mu_1\leq\mu_2\leq\cdots$ enumerate *all* eigenvalues on the different rectangles, the quantity $M(\lambda)$ that you define in the question is just the sum of the numbers of eigenvalues less than $\lambda$ for each rectangle, i.e
$$
M(\lambda)=\sum_p N_{D_p}(\lambda).
$$

Once you see this, then the rest follows easily,
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}\frac{M(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}\sum_p\frac{N_{D_p}(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\sum_p\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}\frac{N_{D_p}(\lambda)}{\lambda}=\sum_p\frac{A(D_p)}{4\pi}=\frac{A(D)}{4\pi}.
$$